# No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'getObjectAtIndex:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode

I am making this app that gets some data from the url (censored). The problem is that I didn't found a solution to get what the PHP script echo.

A normal returned array from that script looks this:

```
{"user_data":  {"id":"78","image":"https://www.i********p.com/uploads/ideas/fun/2017/03/28/78.jpg","idea":"Join Facebook groups related to your passions or hobbies and meet friends.","owner_ID":"1","owner":"Eduard","owner_photo":"https://www.i********p.com/uploads/members/1/1.png","rating":"4","reviews":"1 review","msg":"success"}}
```

The question is how can I access each value of this array from "user_data" using Objective-c (without a loop)?

The Objective-c code:

```
- (void)getJSON {
NSError *error;
NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://www.app.i******o.com/getidea.php?topic=%@", ideasTopic];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url_string]];
NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@", error);
} else {
    NSLog(@"json: %@", json);
    NSLog(@"IMAGE: %@", [[json getObjectAtIndex:0] getObjectForKey:@"image"]);
}}
```

Comment: [[json getObjectForKey: "user_data"] getObjectForKey:@"image"] tell me what is the error

Comment: Same error but this time is for 'getObjectForKey'

Comment: The instance method for getting any object at any index of an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` is [objectAtIndex:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1417555-objectatindex). You are using an extra _get_ before the name of the method. However your `json` is deserialized into `NSDictionary` which will not be accessible by `objectAtIndex`. See the answers below.

Comment: I tried this with no build problem and the console told me unrecognized selector to instance. The code: NSLog(@"IMAGE: ℅@", [[json objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"image"]);

Comment: First change your `json` variable type to `NSDictionary` and then access your data like: `json[@"user_data"][@"image"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C supports literal version to access dictionary. You can directly access values by using keys.

```
NSString *imageUrl = json[@"user_data"][@"image"];
```

Your `json` is a dictionary of dictionaries. `json[@"user_data"]` returns a dictionary with keys and values. You can access values for this dictionary through respective keys.  **json[@"user_data"][@"image"]**  gives you required value for respective key.

**Edit:**
You need to change your `json` variable type to `NSDictionary` too.

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: No, like that it told me to add @ before the strings. And after screams: Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSMutableArray *'

Comment: M sorry i skipped @. In the sample json you have provided there are no array. It seemd to be dictionary of dictionaries. Do check your response and let me know.

Comment: Well, the final PHP script that echo looks like this: $reponse = array("id"=>"$idea_ID","image"=>"$image",..etc); echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$response));exit();

Comment: PanameraTurboS as pointed out by @nyem you need to change your json to NSDictionary. You had declared it as NSMutableArray hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON text you provided is deserialized into NSDictionary object (you can check it yourself, by looking up what class a **json** variable has in your example).

So to get what you want (ex. image), you simply write

```
json["user_data"]["image"]
```

Comment: I tried and: Indexing expression is invalid because subscript type 'char *' is not an Objective-C pointer